# Linear Regression - Similar Results When Predicting in Python

Tags: python

So I am using Linear Regression as my algorithm to forecast the number of customers for the next 28 days using the number of customer for the past 28 days. The program is running and is displaying results, without any errors. However, the results are not promising to me. I was expecting to have results that really differ daily for 28 days. But the predictions each day looks similar to another. 3 or 4 days are the same, and then changes.

This is the results:

```
[14.26112957]
[14.52956811]
[14.79800664]
[15.06644518]
[15.33488372]
[15.60332226]
[15.8717608] 
[16.14019934]
[16.40863787]
[16.67707641]
[16.94551495]
[17.21395349]
[17.48239203]
[17.75083056]
[18.0192691] 
[18.28770764]
[18.55614618]
[18.82458472]
[19.09302326]
[19.36146179]
[19.62990033]
[19.89833887]
[20.16677741]
[20.43521595]
[20.70365449]
[20.97209302]
[21.24053156]
[21.5089701]
```

Im using this code:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/filipinofunnelsdb')

#Fetch dataset
sql = '''
    SELECT order_date as 'date', COUNT(orderstatus) as 'customers'
    FROM orders
    WHERE sellerid = 30
    GROUP BY order_date
'''
# data = pd.read_csv("Customers.csv")
data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['date']=data['date'].map(datetime.datetime.toordinal)

#Prepare 28 days
dateNow = datetime.datetime.now().toordinal()
dates = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
i = 0
while i < 28:
dates[i] = dateNow + (i+1)
i += 1

# Create Linear Regression Model
linreg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(data[['date']], data.customers)

#Predict customers using the dates
predictedValues = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
j = 0
while j < 28:
predictedValues[j] = (linreg.coef_ * dates[j]) + linreg.intercept_
print(predictedValues[j])
j+=1
```

Comment: you have a linear equation `(linreg.coef_ * dates[j]) + linreg.intercept_` what did you expect the results to be but a line?

Comment: is there another equation you know so that i wouldnt have results like that?

Comment: You can fit whatever you want to your data with scipy.optimize.curve_fit https://scientific-python-101.readthedocs.io/scipy/fitting_curves.html